# Server error after ASP.Net application deployed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

Server Error in '/MyApp' Application.
Runtime Error
Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Details: To enable the details of this specific error message to be viewable on remote machines, please create a  tag within a "web.config" configuration file located in the root directory of the current web application. This  tag should then have its "mode" attribute set to "Off".

```
<!-- Web.Config Configuration File -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the "defaultRedirect" attribute of the application's  configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I have done the first suggested  solution but still the same screen is appeared.
Can anyone tell me how to fix it? How can I see the error on Client PC?

Comment: Where are you deploying your application? Is it a local or remote server?

Comment: I am deploying it on my pc for my LAN users.

Comment: Set customErrors to Off and try to attach the webserver process with Visual Studio to see what's going on. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37182/Debug-your-ASP-NET-Application-while-Hosted-on-IIS

Answer (score 2):

You should set customErrors-mode to Off:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

This will allow you to see the error from anywhere, not only your local PC. I'm guessing your accessing your PC through the LAN, otherwise you should already be seeing the error displayed (if accessing from your local PC)

Note: remember to set it back to on once your problem is solved so your not giving information to possible attackers

Comment: Hm, I now see that you had that in your answer. Sorry for that. If you have this configured you should see the error though. If not you have either not edited the correct web.config or you're not accessing the correct web application as this will definitely show custom errors.